# angular deployment - deploy modules with semantic version

Tags: angular, build, devops, semantic-versioning, monorepo

We have a single repo for our angular application, with 4 different teams working on their respective modules. The problem is that the master branch is used to deploy the application on different environments. For example dev , qa, and uat all use the master branch to deploy the application onto a S3 bucket for the respective env. For prod, we cut off a release branch and deploy that. This posses some challenges, mainly all the teams have to follow the same release schedule.

I am doing some research on how to break this dependency and have been looking at monorepos. Additionally, an idea that I had is if we could use a local registry to publish private packages and in turn create different versions of our modules and create different builds.

for example , if we had 4 modules: module 1, module 2, module 3, module 4
Is it possible to create different angular builds using a config file like so :

dev

- module 1 : 1.2.1
- module 2 : 1.2.1
- module 3 : 1.4.1
- module 4 : 2.1.1

qa

- module 1 : 1.2.0
- module 2 : 1.1.1
- module 3 : 1.2.1
- module 4 : 1.5.7

uat

- module 1 : 1.0.0
- module 2 : 1.0.0
- module 3 : 1.0.0
- module 4 : 1.0.0

Comment: I'm working on a tool to deal with this sort of problems - https://relizahub.com - if this looks reasonable, ping me on twitter @taleodor and I'll help you set this up. Note that monorepo per se won't solve this (and it sounds like you are already working in a monorepo pattern - as you say you have single repo for all modules). What you need is some book-keeping of your releases (what Reliza does) + could look more closely at your process, since if you constantly have issues with different pace of different teams, this may be more on the process side of things.

Comment: @taleodor thanks for replying, will take a look and get back to you.